# Is there a straightforward way to lower/increase wifi transmit power on android devices?

Tags: wi-fi

As an example I can easily adjust wifi transmit power on Windows 10 in the wifi adapter properties.

[image]

Do you know if anything analogous could be done on Android?

Comment: Because Wifi is a drain on battery, Android makes efforts to optimize wifi. This is probably why you won't see such possibility